# Proving $|f(x)| < |x|$ given $|f'(x)|<1$ and $f(0)=0$

Tags: functions, derivatives

Given that $f(x)$ is a differentiable function for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and that $f(0)=0$ and $\left |\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right | \leq 1$.

How can we show that $|f(x)|\leq |x|$.

**My answer:**
I cannot seem to prove it mathematically even though intuitively the answer is clear. We know that $f(x)$ passes through $(0,0)$ and that the slope is less than 1 hence it clearly should be bound by the region under $|x|$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: Thank you ! What I did is use the mean value theorem using as follows f(x)-f(0) = f'(c) (x-0) .... f(x)= f'(c)* x ..... f(x)/x = f'(x) then and then take absolutes and things go smoothly. Is that correct ?

Comment: The choice of x here instead of a constant b is because its continuous over R so any b would do .Correct?

Comment: @HasanHammoud That second comment is correct, as long as $x \neq 0$ but for $x = 0$ you are ok anyway.

Answer (score 1):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, since $f(0)=0$ one has that for $x>0$
$$f(x)=\int_{0}^xf'(x)\,dx\leq \int_0^x1\,dx=x$$
Repeating the process for $x<0$ gives a similar result.